# What is the correct way to send an email in canvas app on button click event in Power Apps

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

We are developing an Interview Tool in which we have a a module for scheduling interviews. So here, we need to send email on the button click event. So I've used the Gmail.SendEmailV2 method, but this is not working as required, since the method is resulting in random behavior. I've developed the following code on the OnSelect method of the button

```
Gmail.SendEmailV2(sch_Email, 
                  {
                     Subject:"Enter the email title here", 
                     Body: Concatenate(
                         "Hello ",
                         "<b>",Text(ComboBox37.Selected.CandidateName),",","</b>","<br>",
                         "Hope you're doing well",
                         "<br>",
                         "This email is regarding update for your interview","<br>",
                         "Please find more details below: <br>",
                        "Interview Round:" ,Text(Round_value_2.Text),"<br>",
                        "Date:",Text(DatePicker6.SelectedDate),"<br>",
                        "Time:",interview_hours.Selected.Value ," : ",interview_minutes.Selected.Value,"<br>",
                        "Profile:",Text(ComboBox24.Selected.Position),"<br>",
                        "Interviewer:",
                        Text(ComboBox42.Selected.FullName),"<br>",
                        "Mode of Communication:",Text(Comm_DropDown_2.Selected.Value),"<br>",
                        If(
                                Comm_DropDown_2.Selected.Value ="Online",
                                Concatenate(
                                    "Meeting link:",
                                    DataCardValue21_2.Text,"<br>",
                                    "Thank you for your interest in this profile"
                                ),
                                Comm_DropDown_2.Selected.Value = "Offline",
                                Concatenate(
                                    "Location",
                                    DataCardValue22_2.Text,"<br>",
                                    "Thank you for your interest in this profile."
                        )


                     )
                     )
                   } 
)
```

PS: For now I'm using google sheets as data source.

I've taken reference from the following URL:
http://powerappsguide.com/blog/post/how-to-send-google-mail-with-the-gmail-connector